# How do I configure Django's auth user model to have a UUID (Postgres DB)

Tags: django, postgresql, uuid, django-users, django-contrib

I'm using Python 3.9 and Django 3.2.  Here is my folder structure

```
+ cbapp
    - settings.py
    + models
        - __init__.py
        - custom_user.py
- manage.py
```

Here's what my customer_user.py file looks like

```
$ cat models/custom_user.py
import uuid

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Additionally, I have configured this in my settings.py file

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'models.CustomUser'
```

However, when I run "python manage.py makemigrations", I get this error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'models.CustomUser' that has not been installed
```

I have no idea what this means.  I have this in my settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cbapp',
]
...
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'models.CustomUser'
```

Comment: Seems like your module that containing the models that didn't initialize during the Django startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**According to [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model), to substitute a custom User model**

1. You create your custom user model ( you did it already )
2. In `settings.py`, point **AUTH_USER_MODEL** to it ( the model, you create above ) like this:

   ```
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
   ```

   *You error is here :* instead of `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'models.CustomUser'`
   write `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'cbapp.CustomUser'`

**NB :** Don't point your models file but your `app_name` then the `model_name`.